# Удалить из строки символы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить из строки ' и { чтоб получить чисто число 225

```
Сумма: {'225'} руб
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто замените:

```
s = s.replace('{', '')
```

Answer (score 5):

Так?

```
myString = "Сумма: {'255'} руб"
print(myString.split("'")[1]) # 255
```

Answer (score 4):

с помощью регулярок еще

```
import re
print(re.findall('(\d+)',"Сумма: {'225'} руб")[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [char for char in s if char in ".1234567890"]
print(s)
s = float(s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
txt = "Сумма: {'225'} руб"
print(txt.translate(txt.maketrans("{'}", "   ")))  # "Сумма:   225   руб"
print(txt.translate(txt.maketrans("", "", "{'}")))  # "Сумма: 225 руб"
print(txt.translate({ord(k): '' for k in "{'}"}))  # "Сумма: 225 руб"
```